# Legal situation for camping in the German Elbsandsteingebirge

Tags: wild-camping, trekking, legality, germany, bivouac

Am I allowed to bivouac in the German Elbsandsteingebirge ([Elbe Sandstone Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbe_Sandstone_Mountains))? If no, is it considered as a peccadillo/unenforced law (Kavaliersdelikt)?

> In both countries ((Czech and Germany)), the mountain range has been declared a national
>   park.

Comment: What is a peccadillo?

Comment: @imsodin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peccadillo though it's not really a word you hear used very often.

Comment: In German it's called a "Kavalliersdelikt". I don't know how to translate it correctly. Linguee says it's translated as "peccadillo" or "petty crime". However, it can be described as a crime which is so common, that you don't get sued for it.

Comment: @OddDeer do you mean a crime where you don't get _fined_ for it? Like say something you may only get a caution or warning for?

Comment: @Aravona A "Kavaliersdelikt" is something which is ethical acceptable in the eyes of the general society. It's a crime which the society doesn't want to be tracked. For example being 5 km/h too fast is a "Kavaliersdelikt" or a "Bagateldelikt" in Germany.

Comment: @OddDeer ahh interesting, sounds more like how we handle littering in the UK then, though most of our crimes have on the spot fines. This is probably why you can't find a decent English translation.

Comment: @OddDeer: I suspect the translation you're looking for might be [unenforced law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unenforced_law).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there are special places where you are allowed to sleep outside if you are climbing there.
And by "outside" I mean without a tent, because these locations are (more or less) weatherproof by having roofs of rock. They usually have a a lot of sand on the ground which makes them quite comfortable.

The local term of such a place is "boofe". They are a bit hard to find, even if you know the location on the map. To be sure, each location should have this sign somewhere: It's usually attached to the rock and very small.

[image: official sign]

Here is an example picture of such a place:

[image: bivouac]

The [website of the national park](http://www.nationalpark-saechsische-schweiz.de/besucherinformation/sonstiges/freiuebernachten/?lang=en) covers this in more detail:

> In the National Park it is **forbidden to sleep outdoors in the open**.
>
> As an exception, and in respect of the tradition of Saxon climbing, it is possible **to spend the night outdoors in 58 marked bivouacs only**, if this is done in **connection with rock climbing activites**. All official bivouacs are marked as such. They are located **outside the core zone.**

I have always been there when climbing or together with people who climb.

There's a (very rough) [map](http://www.nationalpark-saechsische-schweiz.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/BS-Konz-Boofen-_Karte_.pdf) of where the locations are on the website and also a German [pdf file](http://www.nationalpark-saechsische-schweiz.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/BS-Konz-Boofen-_Bekanntmachung_.pdf) about what you are allowed to do and what not. As a member of http://german.stackexchange.com I guess that you have the Sauerkraut to understand German. If you need a translation, please leave a comment and I'll add it to my post.

There's also a German [website that lists all "boofen"](http://www.wandern-saechsische-schweiz.de/Liste_Boofen.htm) with GPS coordinates. But even with those it can be a bit of a challenge to find them, because the paths leading to them are often not labelled, blocked or marked to be for climbers. Try to acquire a map made by Dr.-Ing. Rolf Böhm which is a beautiful map of the Elbsandsteingebirge that shows many of the paths and rock formations in great detail, which is helpful because a GPS distance only a few meters away might mean that it's actually 30m higher and getting to this location might only be possible with a long detour around the mountain.

It should go without saying but **don't make a fire**. Leave the place tidy.

I've done it several times, also in winter. It's a great experience, especially when your boofe is higher up, so you have a great view on sunrise.

Comment: great answer, you indeed covered the most important points. The 'core zones' are the most protected areas. As you said, don't make fires even outside the core zones. I'll add a picture because lots of people don't know **boofen** here I assume ;)

Comment: A pity that I can't +2 this answer! Wow! Many, many thanks. Sorry for that silly comment though. My Sauerkrautness is strong enough btw^^

Answer (score 9):

According to German law, bivouacking (defined as sleeping outside for one night without a tent) is generally allowed in Germany, but only outside from nature protection areas. Camping is generally forbidden outside of designated campsites.

As you mention, large parts of the Elbe Sandstone Mountains are under statutory protection within Saxon Switzerland National Park and protected area surrounding it. There is also Bohemian Switzerland National Park on the Czech side. So, in short, **it is not allowed to bivouac in Elbsandsteingebirge**. You should look for available campsites or bivouac outside of the protected areas. As @null pointed out in his excellent answer, there exists an exception to that rule in Saxon Switzerland National Park - there are designated bivouacking places for climbers one can use.

Source: [Deutscher Alpenverien](http://www.alpenverein.de/chameleon/public/16779/zelten_und_biwakieren_in_den_bergen_16779.pdf)

Comment: From the source: "*In Schutzgebieten ist Campieren in der Regel verboten. Ausnahmen können in den Verwaltungen von Schutzgebieten [...] nachgefragt werden.*" meaning "*In general, bivouacking is not allowed in protected areas. You can ask the administration of the protected area for exceptions*" [Such an exception does indeed exist in the Saxon Switzerland National Park at specific locations](http://www.nationalpark-saechsische-schweiz.de/besucherinformation/sonstiges/freiuebernachten/?lang=en)

Comment: @null I didn't know that, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Do hammocks count as bivouacking or as camping?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is forbidden make a fire, build a tent or sleep outsite also in the national park Bohemian Switzerland. Offical website: [www.npcs.cz](http://www.npcs.cz)

Comment: Worth noting a large part of Elbsandsteingebirge lies in the protected landscape area PLA Labské Pískovce where the rules are different. Or at least people are likely to be more benevolent there.